# Extract value from a particular xml node

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, urllib2

How am I able to extract the source IP relevant for "main.mp3" mount point from the below xml source

My current code gets the first on the list which happens to be for the listen.mp3 mount point, however I would like the extraction to be bound to a particular mount point

**Code that extracts the source IP:**

```
SERVER = 'http://localhost:8382/admin/stats.xml'
authinfo = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
authinfo.add_password(None, SERVER, 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx')
page = 'http://localhost:8382/admin/stats.xml'
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(authinfo)
myopener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
opened = urllib2.install_opener(myopener)
output = urllib2.urlopen(page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(output.read(), "lxml")
print "source ip: ",soup.select('source_ip')[0].text
```

**xml source of the link:**

> ```
> <icestats>
> <admin>ossama@hotmail.com</admin>
> <client_connections>580473</client_connections>
> <clients>32</clients>
> <connections>1217611</connections>
> <file_connections>220</file_connections>
> <host>localhost</host>
> <listener_connections>374451</listener_connections>
> <listeners>29</listeners>
> <location>Australia</location>
> <server_id>Icecast 2.4.2</server_id>
> <server_start>Thu, 15 Feb 2018 21:17:23 +1100</server_start>
> <server_start_iso8601>2018-02-15T21:17:23+1100</server_start_iso8601>
> <source_client_connections>99</source_client_connections>
> <source_relay_connections>0</source_relay_connections>
> <source_total_connections>99</source_total_connections>
> <sources>2</sources>
> <stats>0</stats>
> <stats_connections>0</stats_connections>
> <source mount="/listen.mp3">
> <audio_info>channels=2;samplerate=44100;bitrate=64</audio_info>
> <channels>2</channels>
> <genre>Islamic Talk</genre>
> <listener_peak>52</listener_peak>
> <listeners>29</listeners>
> <listenurl>http://localhost:8382/listen.mp3</listenurl>
> <max_listeners>unlimited</max_listeners>
> <public>1</public>
> <samplerate>44100</samplerate>
> <server_description>Qkradio Station Australia</server_description>
> <server_name>listen.mp3</server_name>
> <server_type>audio/mpeg</server_type>
> <slow_listeners>220</slow_listeners>
> <source_ip>127.0.0.1</source_ip>
> <stream_start>Mon, 19 Feb 2018 23:08:01 +1100</stream_start>
> <stream_start_iso8601>2018-02-19T23:08:01+1100</stream_start_iso8601>
> <title>ibtihal.mp3 - 1</title>
> <total_bytes_read>634036021</total_bytes_read>
> <total_bytes_sent>13637049457</total_bytes_sent>
> <user_agent>Liquidsoap/1.3.3 (Unix; OCaml 4.02.3)</user_agent>
> </source>
> <source mount="/main.mp3">
> <audio_info>bitrate=170</audio_info>
> <bitrate>170</bitrate>
> <genre>Islam</genre>
> <listener_peak>2</listener_peak>
> <listeners>1</listeners>
> <listenurl>http://localhost:8382/main.mp3</listenurl>
> <max_listeners>unlimited</max_listeners>
> <public>1</public>
> <server_description>Quran Kareem Radio</server_description>
> <server_name>Quran Kareem Radio</server_name>
> <server_type>audio/mpeg</server_type>
> <server_url>http://qkradio.com.au</server_url>
> <slow_listeners>1</slow_listeners>
> <source_ip>60.241.175.9</source_ip>
> <stream_start>Tue, 20 Feb 2018 00:56:23 +1100</stream_start>
> <stream_start_iso8601>2018-02-20T00:56:23+1100</stream_start_iso8601>
> <total_bytes_read>582030204</total_bytes_read>
> <total_bytes_sent>588819584</total_bytes_sent>
> <user_agent>instreamer</user_agent>
> </source>
> </icestats>
> ```

Comment: did you try xpath?

Comment: not familiar...

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the container 'source' tags and collect 'source_ip' tags on each of them, so each IP will be relevant to a mount poin.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
for mount in soup.select('source[mount]'):
    print "mount point: ", mount['mount']
    print "source ip: ", mount.select_one('source_ip').text
```

Or you could create a dictionary and select IP by mount point, eg,

```
data = {
    mount['mount']: mount.select_one('source_ip').text 
    for mount in soup.select('source[mount]')
}
print data['/listen.mp3']
```

If you want to select the IP from a specific point only, just select the 'source_ip' tag on that node.

```
ip = soup.select_one('source[mount=/main.mp3] source_ip').text
print "source ip:", ip
```

Answer (score 2):

I have pasted your XML data into excercise.xml file, and it should work fine with python 3.x

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
filename = 'excercise.xml'
cwd = os.getcwd()
fullFile = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd,filename))
tree = ET.parse(fullFile)
root = tree.getroot()

#Below code will get Child tag and Child attributes
for child in root:
    if (child.tag) == "source" and (child.attrib['mount'] == "/main.mp3") :
        for element in child:
            if element.tag == "source_ip":
                print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), ships with Python.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring(xml)

for s in tree.iter('source'):
    print(s.attrib) # dictionary with all attributes
    print(s.text) # there might also be text
    print(s.get('mount')) # this is the info you want
    print(s.attrib['mount']) # or like this
```